# How to insert and update date in SQL using list view in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am doing my program using SQL and c#.How can I insert a value of date through a datetimepicker in list view from c# to database? What data type should I use in date in SQL database?

First, I would like to insert the date using datetimepicker. Then, how would it be saved in SQL database in the ReservedDate field? (What line of code should I use). Also what data type should I set the ReservedDate field?

Comment: which DBMS you are using?

Comment: if u want to save only the date and not time then you can use `smalldatetime` datatype in sql

Comment: @Rohaan, sorry but smalldatetime datatype also returns date and time value. what can i do to store date only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to convert your `datetimepicker` value to `DateTime`

```
Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker1.Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

`Insert` like

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReservedDate", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

**NOTE:** And its better to use `datetime` datatype for date fields.

**EDIT:**

```
"INSERT INTO yourTableName(ReservationDate) Values( '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "')";
```

and Take your ReservationDate column of type **`date`** in SQL SERVER database.

Comment: thank you so much.
let me share this, I am using this line of code but then an error occurs. what shall i do?

command = new SqlCommand("Insert into reservation (date_reservation,date_service) Values( '" + dateTimePicker4 + "','" + dateTimePicker3 + "',)", MySqlConnection);

Comment: @user3156375 You need to do something like `dateTimePicker1.Value` or `(dateTimePicker1.Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` to insert.

Comment: thank you. it worked. also, i need to ask how can i store date only? because it stores both date and time but i only need to store date only.

Comment: @user3156375 Edited my answer according to your requirements. see EDIT part.